# Removing link uderline in nested div

Tags: html, css

I began to learn html'n'css, but I've encountered one thing that I cannot explain. I have a html file, that has a div which acts like a link (in the application I am setting the div size and want for the whole box to act like a link). I cannot remove the text underline decoration for the text in the div though (Link1 in the Example is always underlined). The selector should be "any div within a link element", and because the link is red, I think it is correct.

I managed to do this by introducing a special class for removing the underline explicitly (Link2 in the Example is ok), but I would like to have all the menu styles in one place.

The question is, whether can someone explain why the removing deco like this (Link1) does not work. Moreover, I would like to ask if the organization of the menu is a good style, or if I should reorganize the code, e.g: having this for example:

```
<a href="index.html" class="menuitem"><div>Blabla</div></a>
```

and the style:

```
a.menuitem {...}
a.menuitem div {width:...;}
```

Here is the minimal (non-)working Example:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <style>
            a div.menuitem {
              text-decoration: none;
              color: red;
            }
            .remove-under {
              text-decoration: none;
            }
    </style>

    </head>
    <body>
            <a href="./index.html">
                    <div class="menuitem">Link1</div>
            </a>
            <a href="./index.html" class="remove-under">
                    <div class="menuitem">Link2</div>
            </a>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Are you sure you should be putting a block level element inside of an inline one? Perhaps you should put the a inside of the div.

Comment: Yes, but then only the link text acts like a link. I need for the whole box to work like this - which is the purpose of the div element. unfortunately, setting width/height for link element does not work..

Comment: @JoeM. See my answer below, but you need to change the `display` of your `.menuitem` like this: `display:block;` then give it a width and height.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Semantically speaking a `<div>` should not go inside an `<a>`.  div tags are block elements where anchor tags are inline elements - and block elements should never go inside inline elements. Instead use `<span>` if you need to stylize something different inline but in your case, additionally, you can add a class to the `<a>` which would work better.

Here is your new code:

```
<a href="./index.html" class="menuitem">
    Link1
</a>
<a href="./index.html" class="remove-under menuitem">
    Link2
</a>
```

You can have multiple classes to an element by putting a space, so Link2 has the class "remove-under" and "menuitem"

Update your CSS to remove the underline:

```
.remove-under {
    text-decoration:none;
}
```

In order to get your whole a tag to be a link (not just the text) add the follow css for your menuitem class:

```
.menuitem {
    display:block;
    width: 100px; 
    height: 50px; /* or whatever your desired width and height */
    background: red; /* to show that the whole anchor will be link, not just text */
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This is not the ideal solution. You really should not be putting block level elements inside inline elements.

However, if you absolutely must get it working, you can add `display: inline-block;` to the div.

```
a div.menuitem {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: red;
    display: inline-block;
    width:100%;
}
.remove-under {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 problems here:

1. You can't do something like this

   ```
   <a href="#"><div></div></a>
   ```

   because a is an inline element. What you do here is an invalid HTML code. DO it like this:

   ```
   <div><a href="#"></a></div>
   ```
2. You try to apply text-decoration:none on the div element and you should apply it to the a element.

   ```
   a {text-decoration:none;}
   ```

Comment: I have tried this, but then only the text of the link actually works like a link. I want for the whole box to be clickable, is this possible? (I use the div to set size, because setting the width for a does not work)

Comment: You can try this : a {text-decoration:none; display:block; width:100%; height:100%;}